# Having trouble with the next and previous buttons for Selection JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set a next and before button to act as an option switcher. When I click on the Next button twice I can no longer get the previous button to work and vice versa.

This is for switching the sources of my video according to the next and previous button clicking as well as selecting from the options list.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('video').attr('src',$("#test").val());
  $("#test").change(function(){
    $('video').attr('src',$(this).val());
  });
});
$("#fieldPrev").click(function() {
    $('#test option:selected').prev().attr('deselected','selected');
  $('video').attr('src',$("#test").val());  
  $("#test").change(function(){
    $('video').attr('src',$(this).val());
  });
});
$('#fieldNext').click(function() {
    $('#test option:selected').next().attr('selected','selected');
  $('video').attr('src',$("#test").val());  
$("#test").change(function(){    
$('video').attr('src',$(this).val());
    }); 
});
```

Expected that when I click the previous the previous option will display.

```
<div id="epBtn" style="display:none;">
<button id="fieldPrev">&#10094;</button>
<button id="fieldNext">&#10095;</button>
<select id="test">
 <option value="">-- Select Episode --</option>
 <option value="Season 1/ep1.mp4">EP 1</option>
 <option value="Season 1/ep2.mp4">EP 2</option>
 <option value="Season 1/ep3.mp4">EP 3</option>
 <option value="Season 1/ep4.mp4">EP 4</option>
 <option value="Season 1/ep5.mp4">EP 5</option>
 <option value="Season 1/ep6.mp4">EP 6</option>
 <option value="Season 1/ep7.mp4">EP 7</option>
 <option value="Season 1/ep8.mp4">EP 8</option>
 <option value="Season 1/ep9.mp4">EP 9</option>
 <option value="Season 1/ep10.mp4">EP 10</option>
 <option value="Season 1/ep11.mp4">EP 11</option>
 <option value="Season 1/ep12.mp4">EP 12</option>
</select>
```

Comment: fyi java is not javascript

Comment: Could you provide the html code please?

Comment: There is the html code